# recursively find and copy specific mimetype files

Tags: bash, recursion, find, mime-types

How do I modify the below command in a way that the search and the copy are performed based on a file's mimetype instead of using an extension such as (mp4, mkv, docx, etc)?

```
find . -name '*.wmv' -exec cp {} /media/backup/ \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this, for only video files:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
    file -i "$1" | grep -q ": video/" && mv "$1" /media/backup/
' -- {} \;
```

> file(1) — determine file type

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately, it does not work.  I changed the mimetype to video/x-matroska, video/mp4, but still, nothing is copied. Is there a way just to use as mimetype "video" to get all the video files without worrying about mp4, avi, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try that solution?

```
cp `find . -type f -exec file --mime-type {$1} \; | grep ": video/" | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'` /media/backup/
```

---

The **cp** command has to copy each item from the list (see the expression in the ``) to the folder "/media/backup/".

The **find** expression in the `` have to return the list of files whose MIME type is "video".

The **file --mime-type {$1}** expression has to return the MIME data for each file. (Example of output data: **"./video.mkv: video/x-matroska"**)

The **grep** command is needed to leave only files that have the pattern **": video/"**. (I hope the target files do not contain that pattern in their paths and names).

The **awk** expression is needed to get only the path and file name (without MIME data).

---

Comment: Part of stackoverflow culture is that there is commonly great emphasis placed on code being _robust_, meaning that it works reliably even in odd cases.  With that in mind, note that the present version of your code will fail if any of the video files contain spaces or colons in their names.  The problem with spaces is due to the use of command substitution (the back quotes) while the problem with colons is due to the `awk` command.

Comment: To avoid those problems, try, for example, `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file -b --mime-type "$1" | grep -q "video" ' Find {} \; -a -exec mv -t /media/backup {} \;` .  This uses two `-exec` commands.  The first checks for video files and the second, which moves, is only executed if the first succeeds.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why the Find with capitol F? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: @Soichiro The `Find` makes no difference whatsoever __unless__ the `sh -c` code generates an error.  If it does, then the shell reports `Find` (with the capital-F) as the name of script that was running.  Since this identifies what section of code caused the error, this can be helpful when debugging.  (As you may have guessed, we didn't have to chose `Find`. We could have chosen any name.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried both

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
    file -i "$1" | grep -q "video/" && mv "$1" /media/backup/
' -- {} \;
```

and

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file -b --mime-type "$1" | grep -q "video" ' Find {} \; -a -exec mv -t /media/backup {} \;
```

The first code also moved some audio files whereas, the second one did not.
Consequently, the second code works better for me.

Anyway, thank you guys for your help.